# Can't modify the table view dataSource from asynchronous calls inside a loop

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I try to reload the TableView after the dataSource finishing updates when all the asynchronous call finished inside a loop. However, it seems the postLike.likeUser gets clear outside of the for scope.

```
class MyTableView: UITableViewController {
let reuseIden = "postLikeCell"

var postLikes: [PostLike]? 

var userFetchingCompleted = false

var userFetched: Int = 0    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startFetchingLikeUsers()
}

func startFetchingLikeUsers(){
    if postLikes != nil{
        for (index, postLike) in postLikes!.enumerate(){
            postLike.likeUser = User(id: postLike.likeUserId, completionHandler: {
        // the User initilizer requires to fetch info from the server
                (succeed, info) in
                    if succeed{
                    self.userFetched += 1
                        print(self.userFetched)
                       print(self.postLikes![index].likeUser?.fullname)

                        if self.userFetched == self.postLikes!.count{
                            self.userFetchingCompleted = true
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return  userFetchingCompleted ? (postLikes?.count ?? 0) : 0
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postLikeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostLikeTableViewCell      
    print(postLikes![indexPath.row].likeUser) //always print nil
    cell.postLike = postLikes![indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


}
```

The sample output of the code above is

```
1   //the first iteration
Optional("Nicholas Tse")
user get cleared //it seems the postLike.likeUser gets deInitialized since I have a deInit in my User class 

2 //second iteration
Optional("Kesong Xie")
user get cleared

nil //this comes from cellForRowAtIndex 
nil
```

My implementation for PostLike class

```
class PostLike{
    let postLikeId: Int
    let likeTime: String
    let likeUserId: Int
    unowned var post: Post
    weak var likeUser: User? //the user who liked the post


    init(postLikeId: Int, likeTime: String, likeUserId: Int, post: Post){
        self.postLikeId = postLikeId
        self.likeTime = likeTime
        self.likeUserId = likeUserId
        self.post = post

    }

}
```

What is the better way for updating the dataSource from asynchronous call

**Update**

I have modified my code using dispatch groups but the result is the same, the postLike.likeUser gets clear away

```
func startFetchingLikeUsers(completionHandler: () -> Void){
        if postLikes != nil{
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { //don't block the main thread
                let loadingGroup = dispatch_group_create()

                for (index, postLike) in self.postLikes!.enumerate(){
                    dispatch_group_enter(loadingGroup)
                    postLike.likeUser = User(id: postLike.likeUserId, completionHandler: {
                    (succeed, info) in
                        dispatch_group_leave(loadingGroup)
                        print( self.postLikes![index].likeUser?.fullname)
                    })
                    self.postLikes![index].likeUser = postLike.likeUser
                }

                dispatch_group_wait(loadingGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    completionHandler()
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Optional("Nicholas Tse")
user get cleared
Optional("Kesong Xie")
user get cleared
nil
nil
```

Comment: Your structure doesn't make sense. How is your User initialiser constructed?  You wouldn't typically have a return value and a completion block. You also have lots of non-thread safe code here; things like incrementing the counter in the completion block. You should use a dispatch_group and a dispatch_notify

Comment: Inside my User initializer, I have already used  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { }) and call my completion handler from there. So everything done at the completion block is in the main thread. The User initializer has to fetch information like user fullname, email address from the server and that's the reason why I want to construct a completion block. I want to make sure all the user data are available when the completion block get's executed @Paulw11

Comment: It seems the dispatch_group is what I'm looking for, thanks @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the `postLike.likeUser` always get deallocated is that in my `PostLike` implementation, I have `weak var likeUser: User?`. When the the postLike.likeUser goes beyond the scope of the loop, and since there is no strong reference to the User object, the User gets deallocated. Change the `weak var likeUser: User?` to `var likeUser!` will resolve the issue.

```
class PostLike{
    let postLikeId: Int
    let likeTime: String
    let likeUserId: Int
    unowned var post: Post
    var likeUser: User! //the user who liked the post


    init(postLikeId: Int, likeTime: String, likeUserId: Int, post: Post){
        self.postLikeId = postLikeId
        self.likeTime = likeTime
        self.likeUserId = likeUserId
        self.post = post

    }
}
```

Output

```
Optional("Nicholas Tse")
Optional("Kesong Xie")
Optional("Nicholas Tse")
Optional("Kesong Xie")
```